# How to return initial state from a reducer using Immer?

Tags: javascript, redux, immer.js

I am working on a React project and using Redux for state management. I'm moving from ImmutableJS to Immer, and I'm not sure how to return the initial state with some changes. I was using merge from ImmutableJS, but not sure how to do it with Immer.

I looked everywhere and couldn't find the answer. It seems like setting draft to initial state, and then making some changes doesn't work.

```
export const initialState = {
  initializedAuth: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
};

const authProviderReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case AUTH_USER_NO_TOKEN:
        draft.initializedAuth = true;
        draft.isAuthenticated = false;
        break;

      case AUTH_UPDATE_USER_HAVE_TOKEN:
        draft.initializedAuth = true;
        draft.isAuthenticated = true;
        break;

      case AUTH_SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN:
        draft.initializedAuth = true;
        draft.isAuthenticated = true;
        draft.user = action.payload;
        delete draft.user.session;
        break;

      case AUTH_LOGOUT: {
        // return initialState;
        // draft = initialState; doesn't work
      }
    }
  });
```

On `AUTH_LOGOUT`, I want to return the initial state and set its `initializedAuth` property to true.

Using Immutablejs, I was able to do it like this:

```
case AUTH_LOGOUT: {
    return initialState.set('initializedAuth', true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are following the correct pattern, except that your reducer's `AUTH_LOGOUT` case should work as follow:

```
case AUTH_LOGOUT: {
    return draft[initializedAuth] = true;
}
```

About returning the intialState, there is this section in the docs:

> If you want to initialize an uninitialized state using this
>   construction, you can do so by passing the initial state as second
>   argument to produce:

```
const byId = produce(
    (draft, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            .
            .
            .
        }
    },
    intialState <-- here
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const appReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGOUT:
            return initialState;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.